Facing issue while trying the listview.builder to move to a specfic index in flutter
Here is the ListView.builder widget where UI implementation called trying to move the ListView.builder to a specific index, but it only worked when I didn't interact with the scroll manually; otherwise, it didn't scroll to that index.
  Container( 
    height: 70,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 20),
    child: ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      // physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: lotsData.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        //     var price = "";
        // var title = "";
        // if (lotsData[index].lotState == "CLOSED") {
        //   title = "Closed";
        //   price = "Lot No: ${lotsData[index].lotNo}";
        // } else if (lotsData[index].lotState == "AUCTION") {
        //   title = "Auction";
        //   price = "Lot No: ${lotsData[index].lotNo}";
        // } else {
        //   if (lotsData[index].bidInfo.isNotEmpty) {
        //     if (lotsData[index].bidInfo.first.maxBidderId ==
        //         Provider.of<ModelTheme>(context, listen: false).userId.toString()) {
        //       title = "You Win";
        //       price = "${themeNotifier.currencyCode} ${(lotsData[index].bidInfo.first.maxBidAmount * themeNotifier.currencyRate).toStringAsFixed(2)} ";
        //     } else {
        //       title = "Sold";
        //       price = "${themeNotifier.currencyCode} ${(lotsData[index].bidInfo.first.maxBidAmount * themeNotifier.currencyRate).toStringAsFixed(2)} ";
        //     }
        //   }
        // }
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: ClosingLotCard(
            closingUi: true,
            lotStatus: lotsData[index].lotState,
            price: "Lot No: ${lotsData[index].lotNo}",
            border: lotsData[index].id == data?.id,
            title: lotsData[index].price.toString(),
            image: lotsData[index].photos.isNotEmpty
              ? "${imageUrl}${lotsData[index].photos.first}"
              : '',
         ));
       }),
     ),

I am facing an issue while scrolling to a specific index. If I don't scroll with gestures, it works fine, but when I scroll the list by gesture to any other index, then the _scrollController.animateTo does not work properly. How can I resolve this issue?
Here's the method for _scrollController.animateTo:
 void _scrollToIndex(int index) async {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
          index * 100,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    }
  }

